# Running Multiple Google App Engine Apps from one Domain

Tags: google-app-engine

I would like to have the following:

```
myrootsite.appspot.com
myrootsite.appspot.com/app1
myrootsite.appspot.com/app2
etc.
```

Is this possible? I know I could just make `/app1` be handled by `app1`, but then the redirects and everything wouldn't work unless I explicitly used `redirect('/app1')` instead of the current `redirect('/')`.

Is there a way I can just upload my current apps (`app1`, `app2`, etc.) to the root site and have them work regularly?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can only have one application per site. This means you'll need:

```
app1.appspot.com
app2.appspot.com
```

Comment: This seems to suggest otherwise: http://wiki.web2py.com/Deploying_web2py_on_Google_App_Engine_GAE_

Answer (score 1):

You can register one App Engine application ID and have each subdirectory do different things.  For example, have all URLs under /app1 do one thing, and all URLs under /app2 do another thing.

However, they'll have to be deployed together, and will eat away at the same quota.  They will, in fact, be one application, with URLs that do two completely different things.

Otherwise, what Taylor says is correct, you can only have separate subdomains (either on appspot.com or as subdomains on your own domain)

Answer (score 1):

You can't have multiple apps on a domain without a reverse proxy - but you can have multiple 'subapps' - just configure each one independently using app.yaml / web.xml. They'll share the same datastore and memcache, but otherwise can be treated as separate components.